# Wald statistic with known mean and unknown variance in a Normal Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference

I'm working from the Casella-Berger book and I've run across this problem,
[image: Question 10.35]

I've managed to answer part a and most of part b, however, upon looking in the solutions manual I'm not able to get the same conclusion as them. Their conclusion is,
[image: Solution of the problem]

Now the Wald statistic is defined to be,
[image]

And I understand where the $\hat{\sigma}_\mu$ and $\sigma_0$ come from in the solution. However what I unaware of is how the denominator came to be by using the delta method, defined below,
[image]

As mentioned, I am able to obtain the Fischer Information number without an issue but it's the part on how to use that in the Delta method to obtain the denominator in the Wald statistic.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Alright, so if I use the Fisher information which can be defined as $Var(\sigma^2) \geq \frac{1}{nI(\sigma^2)}$ then I get that that $Var(\sigma^2)=\frac{2\hat{\sigma}^2_\mu}{n}$

Comment: Now, use the delta method, which says the variance of the transform is the derivative of the transform squared multiplied by the thing you just computed.

Comment: That's where I'm a bit confused as I don't know what my $g(\sigma^2)$ is, and I'm sure it's something pretty obvious.